# Call the database without mentioning it explicitly

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have used EF6 code first, and created a context for each database and I want for each CRUD operation to be able to call the database without mentioning it explicitly.

Here are 2 of my contexts:

```
public sealed class FiContext : DbContext {

    public FiContext(string dataBase)
        : base(GetDBConfiguration.GetFConfiguration(dataBase)) {
    }

    public DbSet<ClientsImported> ClientsImported { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
    }
}

public sealed class FranchiseeContext : DbContext {

    public FranchiseeContext(string dataBase)
        : base(GetDBConfiguration.GetConfiguration(dataBase)) {
    }

    public DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
    }
}
```

And here i want to insert some data in my databases:

```
public bool InsertInDataBase(string tableSql, string database, Table table) {
    dynamic tableToObject = Utils.TableToObject(table);
    List<string> resultNameList = tableToObject.ColumnName;
    List<string> resultValueList = tableToObject.Value;
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < resultNameList.Count; i++) {
        dictionary.Add(resultNameList[i], resultValueList[i]);
    }
    switch (database.ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)) {
        case "franchisee":
            using (var ctx = new FranchiseeContext (database)) {
                var user = new Users();
                foreach (var item in dictionary) {
                    var classPropertyType = user.GetType().GetProperty(item.Key).PropertyType;
                    var classPropertyName = user.GetType().GetProperty(item.Key); 
                    var valueFromDictionary = dictionary[item.Key]; 
                    var valueFromDictionaryType = dictionary[item.Key].GetType();
                    if (classPropertyName != null) {
                        classPropertyName.SetValue(user,
                            classPropertyType != valueFromDictionaryType
                                ? Convert(classPropertyType, valueFromDictionary)
                                : valueFromDictionary);
                    }
                }
                ctx.Users.Add(user);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }
        case "fi":
            using (var ctx = new FiContext(database)) {
                var anafClients = new ANAFClientsImported();
                foreach (var item in dictionary) {
                    var classPropertyType = anafClients.GetType().GetProperty(item.Key).PropertyType;
                    var classPropertyName = anafClients.GetType().GetProperty(item.Key);                                
                    var valueFromDictionary = dictionary[item.Key];
                    var valueFromDictionaryType = dictionary[item.Key].GetType();

                    if (classPropertyName != null) {
                        classPropertyName.SetValue(anafClients,
                            classPropertyType != valueFromDictionaryType
                                ? Convert(classPropertyType, valueFromDictionary)
                                : valueFromDictionary);
                    }
                }
                ctx.ClientsImported.Add(Clients);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: So, what exactly is your question? What is not working? Are there any exceptions / errors?

Comment: What do you mean by explicitly? Do you want the database you're calling to be obfuscated in your code? If you want to be able to connect to a database you have to at some point pass in an explicit connection string, no ways around it